# a way to prevent dropdown going above search

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, antd

new react developer here, for some reason when i write 'ni' on search, then dropdown goes above search, how to make sure it doesnt go above search ?:
code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-faraday-ch904?file=/src/component.js
picture:
[image]

Comment: `points: ['bl', 'tl'], // align dropdown bottom-left to top-left of input element` Have you tried reversing this?

Comment: wow now it works but new problem, when using on iphone changing from landscape to portait, width of drop down increases over width of iphone, how to fix this ?